# how to add argv params to visual studio's launch.json file?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to specify, for example, `argv.version = v2.0` to the launch setup for visual studio's "code" IDE.. i get there's a "args" param, but seems to accepts only an array of strings

Answer (score 1):

`"args": ["--version=v1.0", "--cron=suite-invoice"],`